# How to return a list type in FastAPI response?

Tags: python, list, fastapi

My objective is return a list of tags as response.

I have a Tag schema like this in my FastAPI app:

```
class Tag(BaseModel):
    nome: str

    class Config:
        from_attributes = True


class TagList(BaseModel):
    tags: List[Tag] = []

    class Config:
        from_attributes = True
```

I wanted return the following response:

```
{
  "tags": ["t1", "t2", "t3"]
}
```

However, i get the following:

```
{
  "tags": [
    {
      "name": "t1"
    },
    {
      "name": "t2"
    },
    {
      "name": "t3"
    }
  ]
}
```

This is my endpoint:

```
@router.get('/tags', response_model=TagList, status_code=200)
def read_tools(db: Session = Depends(get_session)):
    with db as session:
        query = """
            select 
            name
            from tags
        """
        result = session.execute(text(query))
        tags = [r for r in result]
    return {'tags': tags}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return only tag names instead of full Tag objects, you can modify the read_tools function as follows:

```
@router.get('/tags', response_model=dict, status_code=200)
def read_tools(db: Session = Depends(get_session)):
    with db as session:
        query = """
            select 
            name
            from tags
        """
        result = session.execute(text(query))
        tags = [row[0] for row in result]  # Extracting only the tag names from the query result
    return {'tags': tags}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but does not work. I tryed and receive the folloing answer:
`{'type': 'model_attributes_type', 'loc': ('response', 'tags', 0), 'msg': 'Input should be a valid dictionary or object to extract fields from', 'input': 't1', 'url': 'https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.6/v/model_attributes_type'}`

Comment: I don't understand this. This is a list, and model TagList wait a list. Why the error?

Comment: Your taglist wait a list of Tag. You can update the return object to accept a list of strings instead of Taglist.

Comment: I do in my answer. I updated the response_model as return a list of string.

Comment: if you wants response as { tags: []} you may consider to use 'dict' as response_model. If you want just return the list of string use 'List[str]'

Comment: Sorry,I hadn't seen `response_model` above. Thats works, thanks!

Comment: you could also redifine your class TagList just with tags: list[str], and use response_model=TagList